# Aproximations in dissolutions

Tags: physical-chemistry

In chemistry exercices, when can we use the aproximation: the total volume is equal to the solvent volume? I am confused because if you are not given the density of the dissolution, you either need  to aproximate using the method I am asking about or to say that the total volume is equal to the sum of all the susbtances volumes.
When can I use each approximation?